# image manipulation windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I have an image in a Windows Phone app.  There I have an array containing 10 values, depending on those values I am setting my contrast as

problem is when I am sliding forward it is perfect.  But when reversing back image is not getting to original image.

I have already tried and researched a lot

Actually its a code belongs to code project site---

```
private double lastslidervalue;

private void sliderContrast_ValueChanged(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sliderContrast == null) return;
        double[] contrastArray = { 1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.6, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1, 2.4, 2.6, 2.9 };
        int nIndex = (int)sliderContrast.Value-(int)this.lastslidervalue;
        if (nIndex == -1)
        {
           int nIndex=this.lastslidervalue-sliderContrast.Value
           this.lastslidervalue=sliderContrast.value
        }
        else
        {
            nIndex = (int)sliderContrast.Value-(int)this.lastslidervalue;
            this.lastslidervalue=sliderContrast.value

        }

        double CFactor = contrastArray[nIndex];
        WriteableBitmap wb;
        wb = new WriteableBitmap(wbOriginal.PixelWidth, wbOriginal.PixelHeight);
        //wb = new WriteableBitmap(imgOriginal);
        wbOriginal.Pixels.CopyTo(wb.Pixels, 0);
        int h = wb.PixelHeight;
        int w = wb.PixelWidth;
        for (int i = 0; i < wb.Pixels.Count(); i++)
        {
            int pixel = wb.Pixels[i];
            int B = (int)(pixel & 0xFF); pixel >>= 8;
            int G = (int)(pixel & 0xFF); pixel >>= 8;
            int R = (int)(pixel & 0xFF); pixel >>= 8;
            int A = (int)(pixel);

            R = (int) Math.Max(0, Math.Min(255, (((R - 128) * CFactor) + 128)));
            G = (int)Math.Max(0, Math.Min(255, (((G - 128) * CFactor) + 128)));
            B = (int)Math.Max(0, Math.Min(255, (((B - 128) * CFactor) + 128)));

            if (R > 255) R = 255; if (G > 255) G = 255; if (B > 255) B = 255;
            if (R < 0) R = 0; if (G < 0) G = 0; if (B < 0) B = 0;
            wb.Pixels[i] = B | (G << 8) | (R << 16) | (A << 24);
        }
        wb.Invalidate();
        image1.Source = wb;
    }
```

I am here using value changed event of slider....

after debugging I found that R value is continuosly decreasing after sliding forward.
ex--117,114,101,95   ,but after sliding backward R should be increased but,it is decreasing continuosly like after 95 it is 76....
Please help anybody.............

Comment: Do you have sample code of what you're doing and how it's not working?

Comment: @Deeko---Here is my sample code ...

Comment: my maximum value for slider is 9 and min is 0

Comment: @Deeko--where r u man,help me,Iam trying this for long period

Answer (score 0):

Your contrastArray has only positive values. When you're moving the slider back, you are always applying a positive change to your contrast, or crash your app.

```
double[] contrastArray = { 1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.6, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1, 2.4, 2.6, 2.9 };
```

This is all larger than 1.

Also, this can crash your app:

```
int nIndex = (int)sliderContrast.Value-(int)this.lastslidervalue;
this.lastslidervalue=sliderContrast.value
if (nIndex == -1) return;
```

because sometimes the change can be larger than one in the negative side. This means that you get nIndex smaller than -1 which then crashes here:

```
double CFactor = contrastArray[nIndex];
```

However, you could use this code to get what you want

```
private void sliderContrast_ValueChanged(object sender,     RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    if (sliderContrast == null) return;
    double[] contrastArray = { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.6, 1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.6, 1.7, 1.9, 2.1, 2.4, 2.6, 2.9};
    int nIndex = Convert.ToInt32(sliderContrast.Value);

    double CFactor = contrastArray[nIndex];
    //.... the rest is the same
```

And if you set the starting value for the slider to be Value = 5 (do this in XAML) and make the maximum value a bit larger (to expand for the added values), then the change to the right and to the left should get the contrast higher or lower depending on the slider value. Works on my machine. :)

Comment: not working brother...and here iam using value changed event,not mouse left button up event,so i have to subtract slider values,,initially u said there is no negative values ,where is ur -ve values in code

Comment: doesn't matter what you use. value changed event occurs, and you take the current value. And when I said negative values, I meant negative in contrast sense - those are in between 0 and 1.

Comment: I have already tried ur code ,but now its not working when sliding forward also.

Comment: @Igrali..Hey brother you said it perfectly that i have to apply negative values but I have taken ur code but its not working,so please tell me how can i apply negative value,whether i have to change logic for r g b in middle of the code when sliding backwards.if it is then tell what will be the opposite,I mean logic for  R = (int) Math.Max(0, Math.Min(255, (((R - 128) * CFactor) + 128)));