# How to edit a BitmapImage in Windows Phone 8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have to edit a bitmapimage at pixel level. But [Writeablebitmap Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/%20library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) for windows phone doesn't have [WritePixels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc490065(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

Comment: *What* do you want to edit about the bitmap?

Comment: I want to transform the whole image into another, by randomly changing pixel values. Something like [Steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography).

Comment: Have you tried writing to the `Pixels` array, like in [this other StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16991830/50447)

Comment: Yes i did but that doesn't work in 8.1.

Comment: So you want something more like [the example on MSDN for writing to a `WriteableBitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixelbuffer.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is something you are looking for.
I had the same problem and managed to solve it with this. If you need some other explanation please leave a comment.

```
private static async Task<BitmapImage> ConvertImage(byte[] imageSource)
{
    if (imageSource == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageSource);

    using (IRandomAccessStream randomAccessStream = memoryStream.AsRandomAccessStream())
    {
        BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(randomAccessStream);
        PixelDataProvider provider = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(decoder.BitmapPixelFormat, decoder.BitmapAlphaMode, new BitmapTransform(), ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);
        byte[] pixels = provider.DetachPixelData();

        //Each Pixel is composed of 4 bytes [0]: Blue, [1]: Green, [2]: Red, [3] Alpha
        //Do Here your magic with this pixels byte array

        using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream memoryRandomAccessStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
        {
            var imageBytes = await EncodeImageBytes(memoryRandomAccessStream, decoder, pixels);
            using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                await stream.WriteAsync(imageBytes.AsBuffer());
                stream.Seek(0);
                image.SetSource(stream);
                return image;
            }
        }
    }
}

private static async Task<byte[]> EncodeImageBytes(InMemoryRandomAccessStream memoryRandomAccessStream, BitmapDecoder decoder, byte[] pixels)
{
    BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, memoryRandomAccessStream);
    encoder.SetPixelData(decoder.BitmapPixelFormat, decoder.BitmapAlphaMode, decoder.PixelWidth, decoder.PixelHeight, 96, 96, pixels);

    await encoder.FlushAsync();

    var imageBytes = new byte[memoryRandomAccessStream.Size];

    await memoryRandomAccessStream.ReadAsync(imageBytes.AsBuffer(), (uint) memoryRandomAccessStream.Size, InputStreamOptions.None);

    return imageBytes;
}
```

Comment: Stupid but which namespace am I missing? The name `EncodeImageBytes` does not exit in the current context.

Comment: Sorry @alihamza. I forgot to add that method.

Comment: @Meneses Every 4th index of `pixels` is overwritten with a value of '255', no matter what image i provide. I highly suspect that 'GetPixelDataAsync()' is overwriting this value. Is there any alteration resistant solution to this?